# How to fix Cannot read property 'exportDataAsCsv' of undefined

Tags: angular, ag-grid

New to angular + AG grid and attempting to implement export to CSV working from AG Grid, but getting 'Cannot read property 'exportDataAsCsv' of undefined' when clicking the actual export button. Have gone through the example on the example on the AG Grid site.

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../dashboard/dashboard.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projectvariations',
  templateUrl: './projectvariations.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projectvariations.component.css']
})
export class ProjectvariationsComponent implements OnInit {

  private gridApi;

  /* Define our Grid Name & Column definitions for AGGrid */
  title = 'variations'

  // Define our Columns
  columnDefs = [

    { headerName: 'Number', field: 'Number', sortable: true, filter: true, width: 120 },
    { headerName: 'Revision', field: 'Revision', sortable: true, filter: true, width: 70 },
    { headerName: 'Type', field: 'Type', sortable: true, filter: true, width: 100 },
    { headerName: 'Description', field: 'Description', sortable: true, filter: true, width: 930 },
    { headerName: 'Date', field: 'Date', sortable: true, filter: true, width: 80 },
    { headerName: 'Client PO', field: 'Client PO', sortable: true, filter: true, width: 100 },
    { headerName: 'Status', field: 'VarStatusName', sortable: true, filter: true, width: 100 },
    { headerName: 'Currency', field: 'Currency', sortable: true, filter: true, width: 100 },
    { headerName: 'Value', field: 'Value', sortable: true, filter: true, width: 100 },
    { headerName: 'AUD Value', field: 'Value AUD', sortable: true, filter: true, width: 100 }

  ];

  onBtExport() {
    var params = {
      skipHeader: false,

    };

   this.gridApi.exportDataAsCsv(params);
  }
  // 
  @Input() projid:string=""; 

  /** rowData var */
  rowData: any;

// Function which sets params to new HttpParams, sets them to projID input and passes to api.
getVars(projid: string) {
  const params = new HttpParams()
  .set('ProjID', projid)

  this.rowData = this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/ProjectVariations?', { params });
}


  //Add HttpClient for use in constructor
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.getVars(this.projid)

  }
```

HTML: The Html of the component

```
<div ag-grid="gridOptions" class="ag-theme-bootstrap" >

<h2>Project Variations</h2>
<label style="margin-left: 0px;"> <button (click)="onBtExport()">Export to 
CSV</button> </label>

  <ag-grid-angular 
      style="height: 500px;" 
      class="ag-theme-balham"
      [rowData]="rowData | async" 
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      >
  </ag-grid-angular>

</div>
```

Comment: `private gridApi;` is never assigned a value

Comment: I have assigned it a value before ngOnInit, but still get the same error:

          onGridReady(params) {
          this.gridApi = params.api;
           }

Comment: Does your grid render as expected? Please share your export button template [html]. Can you also please share html of this component?

Comment: Hi, yes the grid does render as expected. I have updated to include the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign `this.gridApi` the value of the ag-grid api. You can do this using the `GridReady` event (see [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#miscellaneous).

Change your html to:

```
<ag-grid-angular 
      style="height: 500px;" 
      class="ag-theme-balham"
      [rowData]="rowData | async" 
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
      >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Notice the `gridReady` event.

Then in your component add:

```
onGridReady(params) {
     this.gridApi = params.api; 
}
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-evlkau) StackBlitz as an illustration of this using your code.